# JS DOM equivalent for JQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is the standard DOM equivalent for JQuery

`element.append("<ul><li><a href='url'></li></ul>")`?

Comment: Does it have to be a string you're appending?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you have to extend the innerHTML property to do this

```
element[0].innerHTML += "<ul><li><a href='url'></a></li></ul>";
```

some explanation:

- [0] needed because `element` is a collection
- += extend the innerHTML and do not overwrite
- closing `</a>` needed as some browsers only allow valid html to be set to innerHTML

Hint:
As @dontdownvoteme mentioned this will of course only target the first node of the collection `element`. But as is the nature of jQuery the collection could contain more entries

Comment: @Tobias Krogh Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: @Shayan can you give a bite more context? You cannot just put that line into the console or a script. `element` needs to be a jQuery collection

Comment: @dontdownvoteme can you give a bit more context? What is `element` when you tried that? Maybe a small code block would help 

Comment: @TobiasKrogh using [0] you are trying to access the first element only.

Comment: @dontdownvoteme indeed! I added this as a hint to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 22):

Proper and easiest way to replicate JQuery append method in pure JavaScript is with "insertAdjacentHTML"

```
    var this_div = document.getElementById('your_element_id');
    this_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<b>Any Content</b>');
```

More Info - [MDN insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, especially when working with templates and form elements. Using `innerHTML+=` will overwrite the user's text input values.

Answer (score 11):

Use DOM manipulations, not HTML:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('element');

let list = element.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
let item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
let link = item.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));

link.href = 'https://example.com/';
link.textContent = 'Hello, world';
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

This has the important advantage of not recreating the nodes of existing content, which would remove any event listeners attached to them, for example.

Comment: Agreed; this is definitely the way I'd suggest.

Comment: element is a jQuery collection... so you would need `element[0].appendChild(list);` in my humble opinion

Comment: @TobiasKrogh: I'd think that if the OP doesn't want to use jQuery to append an element, then the OP is not using jQuery any more. In my humble opinion.

Comment: well, he did not wrote that... the question was what would be standard DOM equival... ah whatever...

Comment: @minitech. :) I believe it's a curiosity question and not a real need.

Comment: @gdoron: Well, I actually happen to be moving a current project away from jQuery entirely. So maybe it's real-world :)

Comment: I did not wanted to start a discussion ;) I just wanted to point to the fact that `element` in the question and `element` in this answer will not be the same :)... I promise to be more precise the next time :)

Comment: @minitech: it's a curiosity AND a real project. I want move an entire project to standard JS. I don't want to re-invent the wheel but I simply don't like JS libraries (because I don't always understand what they do and how).   :-)

Comment: @minitech: the way you suggest is what I tried first, but, in a mobile context, with scary (!) resources, it seems DOM manipulation can be slower. I found that if you create an HTML string AND then you use append (JQuery method) passing this string is faster, expecially if you are manipulating DOM inside a for loop.

Comment: @Ry- Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: @Shayan See the question

Comment: @Ry- I thought the OP wants an equivalent of the JQuery function because they are not using JQuery anymore? Same case with me!

Comment: @Shayan: Correct. In the question, the element that was formerly a jQuery element is called `element`.

Answer (score 6):

from the jQuery source code:

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
            this.appendChild( elem ); //<====
        }
    });
},
```

Note that in order to make it work you need to construct the DOM element from the string, it's being done with jQuery `domManip` function.

jQuery 1.7.2 [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

Comment: document.body.appendChild("<ul><li></li></ul>") // Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8... at least I get this in Chrome -.- I think appendChild will only work with actual nodes

Comment: @TobiasKrogh: The `domManip` is significant.

Comment: @gdoron can you explain that to me a bit more in detail? what I understood from your answer was (because of the "<====") that that should be the DOM equivalent... but it is not working for me when using HTML... sorry if it is a stupid question, but is domManip natively accessible? (as far as I can see it is a jQuery function) please do not get mad, I just want to understand :)

Comment: @TobiasKrogh. It's o.k. `domManip` is a **jQuery** function and not a native javascript function. you can see it in the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js).

Comment: @gdoron: ah now I get it... so you pointed out what .append() is in the jquery.js... maybe it would have been good to add some explanation as for me the "<====" was leading me wrongly to the thought using .appendChild() for plain html would work

Answer (score 2):

```
element.innerHTML += "<ul><li><a href='url'></li></ul>";
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1